# Conditional url based on NODE_ENV on Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

Is there a way for me to set an url based on whether I'm in development or production?

Currently I have a component with the following code:

```
export default class Search extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps({ query: { location } }) {
        const res = await fetch(
            `http://localhost:3000/api/search?location=${location}`
        )
        const businesses = await res.json()
        return businesses
    }
...
}
```

I would like something that allows me to do the following:

```
export default class Search extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps({ query: { location } }) {
        let res
        if (environment is in developement) {
          res = await fetch(
            `http://localhost:3000/api/search?location=${location}`
          )

        } else if (environment is in production) {
          res = await fetch (
            `https://productionurl.now.sh/api/search?location=${location}`
          )
        }
        const businesses = await res.json()
        return businesses
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Yes, checkout dotenv. You will set a variable in a .env file and then read it from PROCESS.ENV.<CURRENT_ENV>. https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using the `NODE_ENV` environment variable. For a nice developer experience, set up a config file like this:

*/config/index.js*

```js
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

export const server = dev ? 'http://localhost:3000/api' : 'https://productionurl.now.sh/api';
```

Then you can use that inside your `getInitialProps` methods throughout your application.

*/components/Search.js*

```js
import { server } from '../config';

// ...

static async getInitialProps({ query: { location } }) {
  const res = await fetch(`${server}/search?location=${location}`);
  const businesses = await res.json();
  return businesses;
}
```

Make sure that the `NODE_ENV` variable is set inside `package.json` build scripts, which should look something like this.

*package.json*

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production next build",
},
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here's an example on how to setup development and production**

```
const prodConfig = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    API_ENDPOINT: 'http://google.com/api'
  }
}

const devConfig = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    API_ENDPOINT: 'http://localhost:3000/api'
  }
}

module.exports = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production ? prodConfig : devConfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like what alex bennett has commented, using dotenv should work for your case!

To set it up,

1. **Install dotenv** as a dependency on your Node.js project `npm install dotenv --save` then require it in your application `require('dotenv').config()`
2. **Create a file** called `.env` in the root directory of your project with the environment variables that you need in this `<NAME>/<VALUE>` format here: `MY_ENVIRONMENT=production`.
3. **Change** `<VALUE>` to `production` if you're deploying from your hosted server, or to `development` if you're deploying from your localhost.
4. When that's all set up, you can very easily **check the loaded environment variables** in your code like this (from your example):

```js
export default class Search extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps({ query: { location } }) {
        let res
        if (process.env.MY_ENVIRONMENT === 'development') {
          res = await fetch(
            `http://localhost:3000/api/search?location=${location}`
          )

        } else if (process.env.MY_ENVIRONMENT === 'production') {
          res = await fetch (
            `https://productionurl.now.sh/api/search?location=${location}`
          )
        }
        const businesses = await res.json()
        return businesses
    }
...
}
```